# Weird segfault with std::malloc

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm getting a segfault with the following line of code:

```
char* addr = (char*)std::malloc(bytes);
```

When running GDB I see that `bytes` has a value of `851984`. As far as I know that shouldn't be a big deal. I can't seen anything wrong with it for the life of me. Anybody have some suggestions?

The actual segfault error is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
0x00007ffff674dd75 in malloc_consolidate (av=0x7ffff6a87720) at malloc.c:4254
```

Comment: It's been my experience that things like this are caused by corruption earlier in the program.  You can use something like electric fence or valgrind to find such things.

Answer (score 4):

There is (most likely) an issue somewhere earlier in your code which is corrupting heap structures, causing `malloc` to fail on allocation. You should try using a memory error detection tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug this issue.